# Как найти подкаталог в каталоге?

Tags: c++, linux, c

Данная программа должна выводить файлы из каталога и подкаталогов. То, что это реализуется с помощью рекурсии - это да. Но у меня возникла проблема с проверкой на папку. А именно с проверкой **S_ISDIR**. Не совсем могу понять, как это исправить.

```
int inside = scandir("my_projects/", &namelist, NULL, alphasort);
struct stat buff;
    while (inside--)
      {
     if (stat(namelist[inside]->d_name, &buff) != 0)
        {
          if(S_ISDIR(buff.st_mode)){
             //должен зайти, если папка
          }
          cout << namelist[inside]->d_name << endl;
        }
```

Comment: Если Вы пишите на C++ - используйте `filesystem`.

Comment: Было бы так, если б не критерии.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поле `d_name` содержит имя файла. Чтобы передать его в `stat`, надо приписать к нему путь до каталога который вы сканировали. А так у вас `stat` должен сплошные ошибки возвращать.

```
int inside = scandir("my_projects/", &namelist, NULL, alphasort);
struct stat buff;

while (inside--) {
    string s = string("my_projects/") + namelist[inside]->d_name;
    if (stat(s.c_str(), &buff) == 0) {
        if (S_ISDIR(buff.st_mode)) {
            cout << "d ";
        }
        cout << namelist[inside]->d_name << endl;
    }
}
```